# Leaflet vs Mapbox popups -- what has changed? Can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

**I am not understanding how to get basic popups to work when using the mapbox.js library.** Previously, I got popups to work when using plain Leaflet API by doing something like this:

```
L.geoJson(myData, {
    pointToLayer: function(latlng){
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, myStyle);
    },
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name);
}.addTo(map);
```

But, now that I am trying to use mapbox which is built on top of Leaflet, things are a little different. I checked the documentation but it's just not making sense to me. Apparently, Leaflet's original `onEachFeature` option no longer works under mapbox. So, something like this does not work:

```
L.mapbox.featureLayer(myData, {
    pointToLayer: function(latlng){
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, myStyle);
    },
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name);
}.addTo(map);
```

So how do you I do it under mapbox? Here's a [**quick fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qkvo7hav/14/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With Mapbox library, you have to use the `eachLayer` method on your FeatureGroup after initialization, as shown in their tutorial: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-popup/

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qkvo7hav/15/

Comment: Thanks. But, why the additional step? Isn't that counter-productive? Now, it seems you have to create more work to create a popup.

Comment: That would probably be a reasonable request for improvement to submit to Mapbox.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 11/9:** I ended up finding a better way to do this. I can simply add `L.mapbox.marker.style` to the `pointToLayer` option of `L.geoJson` and it will give me the leaflet popups with the Mapbox marker style without having to write the additional `featureLayer.eachLayer` method.

Example ([from docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.3/l-mapbox-simplestyle-style/)):

```
L.geoJson(geoJson, {
    pointToLayer: L.mapbox.marker.style,
});
```